# Getting these three warnings when building my app

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am getting these warnings:

```
Missing class: com.google.android.gms.common.api.Api$zza
Missing class: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzpm$zza
Missing class: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqt
```

Comment: Add some more detail. In which case you get this.

Comment: once do the clean project.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Helpful feedback: @CodeWithVikas asked you for more information, but you do not appear to have provided it. Please be willing to amend questions promptly when clarifications are sought (if only to prevent them from being closed).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the replies. Below solution helped me. cleaning and rebuilding the project removed the warnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Clean project

2.Rebuild project.

If you still get issue. Try updating your google play service api in app/module's build.gradle file as this class is inside Google Play Service API.